# i need to add comment/chat plugins into blogger like as https://kaviijavahouse.blogspot.com

Tags: blogger

.comments .comments-content .icon.blog-author {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
}

Comment: In the event this is an attempt at a legitimate question, and not poorly disguised spam, please review [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not plugin , its blogger inbuilt function
for turn on comments , go to Settings > Posts , Comment and Sharing > Comment Location and Turn on it.